# How can we insert a 'character' inside the syntax of DiagrammeR

Tags: r, diagrammer

I have the following working flowchart created with `DiagrammeR` package.

```
library(DiagrammeR)
grViz(
  "digraph{
  graph[layout='dot',outputorder=edgesfirst,overlap=T,rankdir=LR]

  b[label='population=BARI_POP4_5_PRIMARY_CN.csv']
  c [label='timepoint=12']
  d[label='endpoint=ACR50']
  b->c[label='']
  c->d[label='']
  }")
```

I was wondering how it is possible to insert into this syntax the `variable_x[1]` of `variable_x <- c("population", "timepoint","endpoint")` instead of "population" like:

```
b[label='variable_x[1]=BARI_POP4_5_PRIMARY_CN.csv']
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more? Are you looking to select population given variable_x?

Comment: Yes I edited in order to make it clear. Instead of "population" inserted manually I want to call  it as the 1st component of the variable_x

Comment: You'll need non canonical syntax which uses dplyr like language. I find it more cumbersome. It's available here: https://github.com/rich-iannone/DiagrammeR

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you had in mind?

```
variable_x <- c("population", "timepoint", "endpoint")

cat(sprintf("digraph{
  graph[layout='dot',outputorder=edgesfirst,overlap=T,rankdir=LR]

  b[label='%s=BARI_POP4_5_PRIMARY_CN.csv']
  c [label='timepoint=12']
  d[label='endpoint=ACR50']
  b->c[label='']
  c->d[label='']
  }", variable_x[1])
)
```

Output:

```
digraph{
  graph[layout='dot',outputorder=edgesfirst,overlap=T,rankdir=LR]

  b[label='population=BARI_POP4_5_PRIMARY_CN.csv']
  c [label='timepoint=12']
  d[label='endpoint=ACR50']
  b->c[label='']
  c->d[label='']
  }
```

Comment: Sorry this does not seem to do something